What is the correct usage of "~たいと思います"?
I'm studying at N2 level, but I've never encountered any formal explanation of this grammar point so far in books and other stuff I use. I hear it very often but never really fully studied its correct usage. My understanding is that it's like a polite, indirect way of declaring intentions.
Questions:

How polite is this actually? Can I use this form when talking to superiors at work?
How is it different from つもり?
What are situations where saying this would be weird?


I always parse this expression as something like either "I would like to ..." or "I might want to ..."  But, I find its usage a bit elusive myself too.

Is it really a strange expression? The cultural aspects are one thing, but purely in terms of the shade of meaning, it would seem to be no more than the sum of its parts.

@KarlKnechtel For me a direct translation ("sum of its parts" approach) always seems a bit odd, "I think I want to ..."  It sounds very hesitant, but after hearing it enough in conversation, it's clearly not as uncertain as the direct literal translation into English might suggest.  Right?

@A.Ellett - I always say 〜たいです when I want to say I want to do something and have never felt the need to use this weird combination myself.

This is a versatile expression that can be used whenever you want to say "I think I'm going to ～" or "I'd like to ～", so it's not something to worry about too much. There is nothing special or tricky regarding politeness, either. It's polite enough in almost any formal situation, but if you need to be extremely humble (such as when writing a formal letter of apology on behalf or your company), you may need something like ～したく存じます instead.
As for the difference from ～つもり:

～したいと思います contains たい, explicitly meaning "I want to ～" or "I'd like to ～". On the other hand, ～つもりです does not necessary mean you want to do it. ～つもりだ can also be used for things you are actually reluctant to do or dislike doing. For example, one can say 明日から煙草を止めるつもりです and もう娘には二度と会わないつもりです.
～つもりです describes your current plan or intent about some future event (at least several minutes later). While ～たいと思います can be used in a similar manner, it is also used for more immediate intentions, decisions, desires, etc. For example, you can say both ハンバーグを食べるつもりです and ハンバーグを食べたいと思います before entering a restaurant, but it would be odd to say ハンバーグを食べるつもりです after entering a restaurant and seeing the menu.

Also note that just saying ～たいです without 思います can sound a little immature or unsophisticated in business settings.

Thank you for the very comprehensive answer! I can now start using this with a little more confidence at work .
